# i need some help transfering funds back into my account from a smart contract i accidentally sent funds to

Tags: tokens, exchanges, uniswap, coinbase, transfer

i was using uniswap and i thought i was easily transfering one token into another and somehow i put myself into a smart contract and cant get my funds back.... yesterday i had figured out with the transfer option in write contract function underneath the info of the last person my 672.4 VRS was sent to but i had to pay $3.85 in either and was going to but by the time i was able to transfer the ether i had bought, it had been about 24 hrs and now when im trying to do the same transfer its saying it will cost $1200..... can some one please help me out so im not out $2500....  transaction source code `https://etherscan.io/tx/0x4621958479d6a263f3448547562d4bf135ea808c6a4a80892e9853086c2d53a6`

Where i believe my tokens are now code `https://etherscan.io/token/0xabc430136a4de71c9998242de8c1b4b97d2b9045?a=0x561852228e80d9a41195ecb112a4ca3b66f1158a`

thanks

Comment: If you have the private key for address 0x5618... then it is just sending a token transfer. If you don't have the private key there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: i was afraid that was going to be the answer..... i do not have the private key but im curious, why does the price i owned the vrs for and the price it was transfered for still fluctuate in my past transaction log of my coinbase wallet in the wallet app?

Comment: If you have another doubt it is better to create a new question. I'd say it is a bug in the coinbase wallet.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I have a question I accidentally sent my funds from my usdc wallet to and Eth wallet now it’s on the blockchain I can see the transaction and the token holder adress which was mine how do I access the token ??